# customError on web.config-originated Server Error

Tags: asp.net, web-config

**NOTE**

*I've determined the the problem I'm describing below is specific to an error enountered loading DLL files specified in the `web.config` file. I would like to present a user-friendly error even in the case of `web.config` errors.*

**END NOTE**

When my ASP.Net application encounters a server error I would like it to present a custom error message to the user instead of the following default scary message.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I wrote a very simple HTML page and put it in the root of my application. It is called MaintenancePage.htm.

I've set my web.config file to the following:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="MaintenancePage.htm">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

I've also tried `~/MaintenancePage.htm` and `http://[mysite]/MaintenancePage.htm`. None of those options seem to work.

The way I'm testing this is to rename a DLL my project depends upon and then loading up the site in a web browser. I would expect that since there is an error and a `defaultRedirect` set there should be no problem showing the error page, however, I'm obviously wrong.

I've search around concerning this problem and it seem that most people are trying to redirect to an `aspx` page, and are encountering error with doing that. Many even report that they can't get the `aspx` page to load as a `defaultRedirect`, but they can get an `html` page to load.

What could I be doing wrong here?

I should note that I'm doing my testing from a different network outside the company firewall, so changing `RemoteOnly` to `On` is not the issue per the documentation. In testing changing `RemoteOnly` to `On` had no effect, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Change **RemoteOnly** to **On**.

RemoteOnly:

> Specifies that custom errors are shown only to remote clients and
>   **ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host**

Also, your URL may be absolute or relative.

[Read more about the customErrors settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

To watch it work locally:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/MaintenancePage.htm">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Easier way to test.

1. Try a bad url and watch your 404 error take over
2. Put this on your default.aspx page **<% throw new Exception("gaah"); %>**

And one other thing to consider: Error Logging. Can be achieved easily through [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

Comment: I'm not doing my testing only from the local machine, I'm doing it from a remote machine too and am seeing the same problem. I'll have a look at your other suggestions and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Changing `RemoteOnly` to `On` didn't do anything as I would have expected after reading the documentation. The error I received is the result of testing the page from a remote location; that is to say, not from the server.

Comment: You copied the code from my post for the web.config and then tried test 2? ...and ensured those error pages exist on the server?

Comment: I ensured the error pages exist. I copied your web.config code. However, to test, I renamed a required DLL in the bin folder.

Comment: When I go to a page that doesn't exist, I see my error page. When I put an exception in `default.aspx` then I see my error page inside my master template.